# Zip two differents lists for two rows array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, arraylist

I want to put 2 list in a array with (one rows for one column) like this model : [[w, a, t, l][q, m, v, u]]

That is my confuguration list :
 `data_1 = data_txt_W1[:sl1]`
`data_2 = data_txt_W1[sl2:]`

That correspond to :

- data_1 : [-2.39123179, 2.19363512, -1.73483529, -1.94338542, 0.86847094, 2.18170135, -2.00504699, -0.04422694, 1.38740394]
- data_2 : [-0.14191044, 0.21310374, -0.40452412, -0.32172719, 0.24878486, 0.21668563, -0.2694207, 0.99565063, 0.5039941, -0.06638008]

(They are two lists)
The result I want is an array like that :

```
[[-2.39123179, 2.19363512, -1.73483529, -1.94338542, 0.86847094, 2.18170135, -2.00504699, -0.04422694, 1.38740394]
 [-0.14191044, 0.21310374, -0.40452412, -0.32172719, 0.24878486, 0.21668563, -0.2694207, 0.99565063, 0.5039941, -0.06638008]]
```

I tried

```
data_txt_W1 = np.array([[data_1], [data_2]])
```

but the result is :

```
[[list([-2.39123179, 2.19363512, -1.73483529, -1.94338542, 0.86847094, 2.18170135, -2.00504699, -0.04422694, 1.38740394])]
 [list([-0.14191044, 0.21310374, -0.40452412, -0.32172719, 0.24878486, 0.21668563, -0.2694207, 0.99565063, 0.5039941, -0.06638008])]]
```

And I don't want the word `list()` in the result.

Comment: Try this `data_txt_W1 = np.array([data_1, data_2])`

Comment: `data_1` and `data_2` must have the same number of elements otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Indeed, my 2 lists haven't the same lenght. Now that's work ! The solution is : `data_txt_W1 = np.array([data_1, data_2])` with 2 lists who have the same lenght (the same number of elements). Thanks to @sai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for zip 2 lists into an array with one list for one row (2 lists = 2 rows) is : `data_txt_W1 = np.array([data_1, data_2])` .

/!\ But don't forget : the lists must be have the same number of elements, if not that doesn't work !

Thanks for the quick answer of @sai ,